# Cakephp 2 RequestHandlerComponent does not have a method beforeRender error message and could not parse RSS

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, requesthandler

I got 2 different problems:

1. Error while render default request (html)
2. Error while render rss request.

Here is my code:

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Pages';
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public $helpers = array('Text');
}
```

Below is code for normal request.

```
  //problem #1:
  public function display() { 
    $path = func_get_args();

    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
            $this->redirect('/');
    }

    $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
    }

    if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
    }

    if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
    }

    $this->setDefaultMeta();
    $this->layout = 'default';
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
    $this->render(implode('/', $path));
}
```

And this is for rss request

```
 public function feeds(){  
    if( $this->RequestHandler->isRss() ){ 
        $this->loadModel('Deal');
        $arrId = $this->Deal->DealBuyCondition->listAliveID();

        $posts = $this->Deal->rssFeeds($arrId);  
        return $this->set(compact('posts'));
    }
    die('rss only');
    return false;
}
```

First function returned errors:

```
Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'RequestHandlerComponent' does not have a method 'beforeRender' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 132]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'RequestHandlerComponent' does not have a method 'shutdown' [CORE\Cake\Utility\ObjectCollection.php, line 132]
```

and the second function did not properly rendered as RSS.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your CakePHP setup might be messed up. `RequestHandlerComponent` does have a `beforeRender` method and also `shutdown` method (inherited from parent `Component`) so those errors weird. Try getting a fresh copy of CakePHP.